# Visual Basic I can't Pass 2 value

Tags: vba

I'm making Macros and I got this Erorr where I can't Pass 2 value

```
Public Sub sada(ByRef TxtL As Double, ByRef TxtW As Double)
End Sub

Public Sub Create_Click()
    Dim SadaClient As New SadaClass
    SadaClient.sada(txtlen,txtwid)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Does removing the parenthesis work? `SadaClient.sada txtlen, txtwid` - In VBA, Subs dont use them, but Functions do.

Comment: yes many thanks SadaClient.sada txtlen, txtwid